# What happends when I change the default font in css?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I try to change the default font in the editors in SharePoint 2010. So when I try to add some text on a page, it will be for example "Verdana". I have googled and I can change the current css or create a custom css and add a reference in the masterpage.

I would like to know what happends with all the current content on my portal. Will it automatically change to the "Verdana" font? Or will it be the old font.

Comment: One way to find out: try it. Create a sample site collection in your test environment. Use default settings, create a few pages. Then change the CSS. Then look at the pages. It's as easy as that. Should not take more than ten minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the current content on the site will change when you change the CSS depends on what CSS exactly is applied to the current content. That's not easy to tell without seeing the site.

Different types of content use different ways of defining the font. CSS as in "Cascading" only applies to styles that have not broken (or overwritten) the cascade. Content in rich text fields may or may not have been formatted by the user. If specific formatting has been applied in an RTE field, this will keep.

You may want to inspect your pages with the Developer Tools in Internet Explorer (or similar in other browsers). Use the tool to change the CSS class you would want to change and have a look at the page in the preview. That will give you an idea.

Ultimately, you may want to trial the new CSS in your test environment before you apply it in production, so you can see which pages are affected in which ways.